# Does libcurl4 for amd64 work with Intel Core(TM)i5?

Tags: networking, apt

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my 64 bit desktop (with Intel Core(TM)i5-2400 CPU@3.1 GHz) and I need to setup networking using the internet.
The install is missing the curl package and I do not know what package(s) to download for it.
I looked on curl.se and downloaded curl-8.4.0.zip. Is this the right package?
And how do I compile it on Ubuntu? What compiler should I download and what other packages do I need for that to work?
Many thanks in advance for the info! Much appreciated.

Comment: What is your concern?  Intel i5 CPUs are *amd64* as the intel 64-bit itanium processors failed in the marketplace as purchasers wanted x86 compatibility which *amd64* supplied (it's also called x86-64).  libcurl4 is available ; ie. `libcurl4 | 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.14 | jammy-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`

Comment: Thanks for the info. My concern stems from not being an expert in hardware.

Comment: @Daniela if you installed Ubuntu, then just run `sudo apt install curl libcurl4` - if you can run Ubuntu on your infrastructure then the packages for that architecture will work.  The Intel Core series are all `amd64` / `x86_64` and don't have hardware incompatibilities with *specific* libraries like libcurl4.  If it did, you'd have much larger issues on your system with running Ubuntu among other things

Comment: Thanks for the info Thomas. >"you'd have much larger issues on your system with running Ubuntu" That is correct! I ran already sudo apt install curl libcurl4, and apt-get install and it tells me the package is missing. I have a HPCompaq 6200 Pro SFF PC. @CAAHS; @noisefloor

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a very specific reason to use the self-compile the latest package from source, you can use the curl package from the Ubuntu repository.

To install open a terminal an execute

```shell
sudo apt install curl
```

This will install curl with all necessary dependencies. The package is in the "main" repository, so it receives bugfixes directly from Canonical as necessary.

If you really want to build the latest version yourself: the [curl documentation](https://everything.curl.dev/build) has instructions how to build and compile.

Comment: I did that (sudo apt install curl) and the outcome of it was "Package curl is not available"; "Package curl has no installation candidate"; thanks for the info

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your system. Please open a separate question for this, as you original questions targets a manually compiling curl.

Comment: I'll try first to compile it myself and install it manually. If it is still not working I will open a separate thread. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get this out of the way upfront, [`curl`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/curl) is available as a standard package in Ubuntu 22.04, as is the library ([`libcurl4`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libcurl4)).

For the a little bit indirectly asked question

> Does libcurl4 for amd64 work with Intel Core(TM)i5?

The answer is yes. And more specifically `amd64` is also known as (a.k.a.) `x86_64` so on linux you can treat it vice-versa. It's 64bit architecture `x86` style, all you have with Intel or AMD nowadays, only with few exceptions to that rule, none of you run into with your Intel Core (TM)i5.

Now per your comment that you were unable to run the normally working command (this is how to install curl from the command line), it is perhaps good to see how it looks like

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/194 kB of archives.
After this operation, 454 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package curl.
(Reading database ... 243399 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../curl_7.81.0-1ubuntu1.14_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.14) ...
Setting up curl (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.14) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
```

That is `sudo` to obtain root rights (to configure the system), `apt-get` as the utility to act as the *package-manager* to install software packages system-wide, the sub-command `install` (of `apt-get`) and the name of the package (`curl`).

Afterwards you can test how it worked by showing the version:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.81.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.81.0 OpenSSL/3.0.2 zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.4.8 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.2) libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.5.16
Release-Date: 2022-01-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

If the `curl` package is not available in the configuration of `apt-get` (the  `apt` configuration is in `/etc/apt`) double-check you have the required entries in `sources.list` (excerpt shortened to the `jammy-security` repository which I believe the `curl` package is in):

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20230807.2)]/ jammy main restricted
# ...

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# ...

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

This is where the actual packages are obtained from, there is no need for a source install, e.g. fetching individual source archives and then building the software and installing it.

Comment: Many thanks for the info, CAAHS.

Comment: I also ran cat /etc/ap t/sources.list and the output is too big to list in here but a snapshot of it is deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse

Comment: @Daniela: In my very honest opinion from remote, and also as written in the answer, if you're not offline, it should find the package as it has the required repository. Apart from that, there is more apt configuration inside `/etc/apt` the files therein should be explained in the _manpages_ and I only write it because you need to trouble-shoot your problem further. A start is `man 8 apt-get`, next to the utility descriptions (invocation), it also has a _FILES_ and _SEE ALSO_ section towards the end.

Comment: Thanks CAAHS. My problem stems firstly from not having an internet connection setup properly.  So cannot update curl from anywhere. When doing "apt-cache policy curl", I get "Installed: (none)"  "Candidate: (none)"  "Version table:       " Is there a way to setup the internet connection without needing curl ? I have an "AMT Intel's technology kit" on the desktop (the Compaq 6200 Pro SFF PC). Would that not be compatible with Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Forget `curl` for a moment, you don't need it for internet connection. When you run `sudo apt-get update` does it `Hit: ...` and `Get: ...` the repositories from `sources.list`? It shows some URLs (Uniform Resource Locator) and summarizes at the end that `Fetched 4.312 kB in 2s (2.632 kB/s)` (numbers are exemplary) and finally `Reading package lists... Done`.

Comment: It cannot connect to the internet, therefore when doing "sudo apt-get update", I get "Ign:" about 20 times and then "Err:" resolving archive.ubuntu.com, then "W: Failed to fetch" the dists..... Would reinstalling a different version of Ubuntu help? Firstly, I installed 23.04, but stopped it when stuck on security  page. Then, reinstalled 22.04 and it was successful, except curl. I personally think the AMT gets in the way of installing Ubuntu. I am happy to be proven wrong. To answer, HIT: and GET: do not appear after sudo apt-get update

Comment: So this is like the cat that is hunting her own tail. As long as you're not online you can't download packages from online package sources (package repositories). you have to add an offline media that contains a repository. For example a CD-ROM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-ROM (or DVD, USB Drive etc.). Check the documentation of your operating system (Ubuntu) for your options, this is something you better read about non-interactively and then apply the learned knowledge. /Edit: This is perhaps a good starting point: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoftwareManagement

Comment: This is a good starting point. Thanks.